# css and :empty on table element in IE9

Tags: css

Can anyone figure out a fix for making the table version look like the div version in IE9?

http://jsfiddle.net/tCT9b/2/

```
<table class="foo"></table>
<div class="foo"></div>

div.foo {
    float: right;
}
table.foo {
    float: left;
}
.foo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.foo:empty:before {
    position: absolute;
    background: #eee;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    content: 'None';
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: A valid `table` element can never be empty, so you should have a different approach in markup. Even though HTML validity as such is irrelevant to CSS, browsers may have default processing for HTML elements like `table`.

Comment: It doesn't work with <td> either.